# Unable to connect to the remote server [curl] in spring boot

Tags: java, http, curl

This is the start up of the boot system. just following up the process through the documentation provided at https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-for-azure/.

I'm getting the error as below;

> curl : Unable to connect to the remote server
> At line:1 char:1
> + curl http://localhost:8080
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebR
> equest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsof
> t.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

Comment: The link to the spring document now gives a 404 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer

> > ./mvnw spring-boot:run

will connect to the remote server.

Just posted, cause some one may need help on this